# GLEW initialisation failed

Tags: c++, opengl, initialization, sdl, glew

Im just trying to make an openGL context using SDL 2.0 and glew 1.9

No problem while building the project but while debuging, GLEW fail the initialisation, what can I do to solve this problem?

I'm using visual studio 2012

Here is the output:

```
The program '[936] gravitation.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

And here is the code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Window* window = 0;
    SDL_GLContext contextOpenGL = 0;

    SDL_Event event;
    bool terminate = false;

    GLenum initGLEW = glewInit();

    if( GLEW_OK != initGLEW )
    {
        std::cout << "initialisation error of GLEW : " << glewGetErrorString(initialisationGLEW) << std::endl;

        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(contextOpenGL);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();

        return -1;
    }

    while(!terminate)
    {
    SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

    if(event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)
        terminer = true;

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(contextOpenGL);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a OpenGL window neither a OpenGL context being created in your code. You need a OpenGL context being active when initializing GLEW.

Comment: @user1854186: If you copy and pasted this from a tutorial, you missed a few things. If this is the original tutorial code, then the tutorial is wrong.

Comment: Yea you were rigth i was a bit too fast. That was a stupid mystake :p
Thanx for your help